# Retrieve single tag among all tags

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, meta

I need help with my wordpress site. While displaying "tags" on a product page,

```
<?php echo $product->get_tags(', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

is used to show them.

However, I need product page to show only 1 tag for a product. This code makes all tags to appear on the page. Which code should I use or how should I edit this?

in example:
if a product has the tags: summer, winter, fall, spring
I want only "fall" to be seen

Comment: Did you want only first tag of result set?

Comment: not "first" but "any" I just want to be able to get any one of the tags

Comment: I check it my local but this is not possible with programming you have to apply css for doing that. if you want to do so then i can provide you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        $tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
        $first = true;
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if ( $first ){
                $term_link = get_term_link( $tag );
                if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {continue;}
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
                $first = false;
            }
        } 
    ?>
```

This will only print the first tag in a woocommerce product page. Its tested and working.

If you want to display any selected tag, then you need to define which tag you want to be visible. Maybe using a custom field. Lets say you have a custom field name 'selected_tag' using ACF plugin and it will print the exact tag name that you want to visible in the product page.

```
<?php
        $selected_tag = get_field('selected_tag');
        $tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if ( $tag->name == $selected_tag ){
                $term_link = get_term_link( $tag );
                if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {continue;}
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
            }
        } 
    ?>
```